# Summing values and inserting to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this sql command that sums up the value from a,b,c and d. and i want it to be stored in my table in the column total.
Is this the correct query?
How to store the total value?

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(a + b + c + d) as total_value FROM tablename WHERE form_no = '$formnumber'";
```

Comment: `SUM()` is for summing values from multiple rows. Is that what you're doing? If you're just adding columns in a single row, you just use `SELECT (a+b+c+d) AS total_value`

Comment: i'am trying to sum one row. with 4 columns

Comment: What did you think the difference was between `(a + b + c + d)` and `SUM(a + b + c + d)`?

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE tablename
SET total_value = a + b + c + d
WHERE form_no = '$formnumber'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT (a + b + c + d) as total_value FROM tablename WHERE form_no = '$formnumber'";
```

where a,b,c,d are column name..

This is working fine..check it

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT (a + b + c + d) as total_value FROM tablename WHERE form_no = '$formnumber'";`

`$sql = "UPDATE table_2014 SET a = '$value' WHERE form_no = '$formnumber'";`

i used that code but its not working

Comment: a,b,c,d fields should be an integer..please check whether the data type is integer in mysql... For me its working fine....